# Confused on figured bass in minor

Tags: theory, figured-bass

I’m new to learning figured bass... Why is the last set of notes considered as a capital Roman numeral V instead of vi? The root note shows G.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last chord shows the notes:  G, A, E, C#.
If we rearrange these into a stack of thirds, we get:  A, C#, E, G.
This is a  dominant seventh chord:  A7.
But, as the note G is in the bass it is:  A7/G.

Within a key of D minor, this is represented in roman numeral notation (with the third inversion being shown with a little d) as:  V7d.

In figured bass, the figure 2 implies that this is seventh chord in third inversion, the 4 is sharp as we are in the harmonic minor, and a figure 6 is redundant and so not written.

Answer (score 1):

Dominants are always major chords. You don’t have a g chord there, but an A7, dominant in 3rd inversion (G on bass). So, G isn’t the root.

- G on bass;
- 2 refers to A;
- 4 sharp refers to C#;
- 6 refers to E (usually omitted).